# Comment traduire « it sounds like X » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

Dans le sens du son de quelque chose ressemblant à un autre son… en anglais, on dirait quelque chose comme « “La fac” sounds a lot like a common English swear. »

Quel est le meilleur moyen de traduire ça ?

Comment: By the way, is "...de traduire ça?" okay to say? As opposed to "...de le traduire?"  I'm trying to distinguish between "...to translate it?" and "...to translate that/this?"

Comment: De traduire ca is ok :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En français, en général, on utilise un verbe générique comme *ressembler*. Si nécessaire, on précise l'aspect qui ressemble par un complément.

> « La fac » ressemble beaucoup à une grossièreté courante en anglais.
> « La fac » ? Oralement, on dirait une grossièreté courante en anglais.
> Pour une oreille anglophone, « la fac » a l'air d'une grossièreté courante.
> « La fac » ? À l'entendre, ça me fait penser à une grossièreté courante en anglais.

Le phénomène est similaire à des expressions comme « *he walked up the hill* », où le français dira en général « il est monté sur la colline » et ne précisera « en marchant » que si c'est vraiment nécessaire.

Le verbe [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sonner) peut signifier « faire un bruit d'un certain type », et on peut dire « sonner comme quelque chose ».

> Ce bruit mystérieux sonne comme un départ. [(Charles Beaudelaire, *Les Fleurs du mal*, 1857)](http://books.google.fr/books?id=VMj1Px79Q8kC&pg=PT33&dq=%22sonne+comme%22)
> Dans les verbes, cette finale sonne comme en français. [(Achille Delboulle, *Glossaire de la vallée d'Yères*, 1876)](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5v2gMgaCbtkC&pg=PA302&dq=%22sonne+comme%22)
>
> « La fac » sonne comme une grossièreté en anglais.

Je trouve cette formulation moins idiomatique.

Pour une odeur ou un goût, il y a des expressions plus spécifiques qui sont plus idiomatiques.

> Ce potage a un goût d'épinards.   *This soup tastes like spinach.*
> Il y a une odeur de brûlé.   *It smells like something's burning.*
> Ça sent le brûlé.   *It smells like something's burning.*

Pour la vue ou le toucher, par contre, on utilise en général les termes génériques.

> Elle ressemble à sa mère.   *She looks like her mother.*
> On dirait de la soie, c'est si doux !   *ou*   C'est doux comme de la soie.   *This feels soft like silk.*